# ElasticSearch log search query for user

Tags: elasticsearch

We have built a Repo Document Search Engine[**RDSE**] using ElasticSearch.

**System Current Architecture:**

[image]

Multiple users from multiple organisation will use the RDSE.

I want to log those queries done by user is that possible in ElasticSearch.

We need to audit those query along with the user information this would enable us to analyse the search queries being performed by different groups of users.

This would give us insight into what a particular group of user or organization wants or interested in.

I found something similar to this on Elastic Search blog [monitoring the queries](https://www.elastic.co/blog/monitoring-the-search-queries)

We can use the above method to monitor queries but we cannot match with the users.

**Current Suggested Architecture:**

[image]

Is there any way to directly audit the ElasticSearch Search query along with the user information to another ElasticSearch?.

Comment: I must admit, that your questions are very vague. What do you mean, if ES supports those placeholders? Where? I mean, one could implement with ES client anything? Could you be more specific in what are you using for example and what did you try so far?

Comment: Sorry, @Mysterion for being vague. In short, I want to find the queries used by user/organisation. I thought if ElasticSearch has support to such Place Holders I can get the queries used by User and Organisation by querying for them. Is this making Sense?. i.e.) Google knows the queries done by you so they save both the query and user. I want to know if something like that is available ElasticSearch

Comment: Let me rephrase it one more time. ES itself provides HTTP API, of course there is no support in a plain HTTP to support placeholders. However, if you going to use some ES clients (Java, Python based) or even anything with plain HTTP request, of course you could do those templates, by implementing them.

Comment: @Mysterion If I go on to do them I would be getting `"type": "parsing_exception", "reason": "Unknown key for a VALUE_STRING in [user]."`.

Comment: My current solution is, I am logging all the queries done by the user through by Application(.net Client) to a log file. From there I use Filebeat to read the log and write them to ElasticSearch.

Comment: okay, this is because your query syntax is incorrect. okay i got your problem, hold on

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167806/discussion-between-the6thsense-and-mysterion).